# Postgresql Query Optimization with many left joins

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine query that is taking seconds to run.  I'd like to make sure that it's going as fast as I can make it.  The query is the following (coming from Doctrine):

```
SELECT DISTINCT task.id AS id0,
                task.rate AS rate1,
                task.revised_rate AS revised_rate2,
                task.title AS title3,
                task.points AS points4,
                task.due AS due5,
                task.created AS created6,
                invoice.id AS id7,
                invoice.title AS title8,
                company.id AS id9,
                company.customer_code AS customer_code10,
                taskStatus.id AS id11,
                taskStatus.title AS title12,
                priority.id AS id13,
                taskUser.id AS id14,
                taskUser.firstname AS firstname15,
                taskUser.lastname AS lastname16,
                invoiceUser.id AS id17,
                invoiceUser.firstname AS firstname18,
                invoiceUser.lastname AS lastname19,
                invoiceStatus.id AS id20,
                invoiceStatus.title AS title21,
                opportunity.id AS id22,
                opportunity.name AS name23,
                SUM(slip.stop - slip.start) AS sclr24,
                task.projected_minutes AS projected_minutes25
FROM task task
INNER JOIN invoice invoice ON task.invoice_id = invoice.id
AND (invoice.deleted IS NULL)
INNER JOIN company company ON invoice.company_id = company.id
LEFT JOIN task_status taskStatus ON task.status_id = taskStatus.id
AND (taskStatus.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN slip slip ON task.id = slip.task_id
AND (slip.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN fos_user taskUser ON task.user_id = taskUser.id
AND (taskUser.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN priority priority ON task.priority_id = priority.id
AND (priority.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN task_comment taskComment ON task.id = taskComment.task_id
AND (taskComment.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN task_file taskFile ON task.id = taskFile.task_id
AND (taskFile.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN task_step taskStep ON task.id = taskStep.task_id
AND (taskStep.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN fos_user invoiceUser ON invoice.user_id = invoiceUser.id
AND (invoiceUser.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN invoice_status invoiceStatus ON invoice.status_id = invoiceStatus.id
AND (invoiceStatus.deleted IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN opportunity opportunity ON invoice.opportunity_id = opportunity.id
LEFT JOIN fos_user slipUser ON slip.user_id = slipUser.id
AND (slipUser.deleted IS NULL)
WHERE (taskStatus.id IN (3)
       AND slipUser.id IN (605))
  AND (task.deleted IS NULL)
GROUP BY task.id,
         company.id,
         taskUser.id,
         taskStatus.id,
         invoice.id,
         invoiceUser.id,
         invoiceStatus.id,
         opportunity.id,
         priority.id
ORDER BY priority.id ASC, task.due ASC, company.customer_code ASC, taskUser.firstname ASC, taskUser.lastname ASC, task.points ASC, task.title ASC, taskStatus.title ASC, task.created ASC, invoice.title ASC, invoiceUser.firstname ASC, invoiceUser.lastname ASC, invoiceStatus.title ASC, opportunity.name ASC LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

And here is a [link to the explain](http://explain.depesz.com/s/TouD).

[Task table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/EbudRuDw)

[Invoice table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/drJgVkkN)

[Company table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/7sBwUAup)

[Task status table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/xaRdaEXF)

[Slip table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/LcPL7Su8)

[fos_user table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/9E0KW97D)

[Priority table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/tdzA8rLu)

[Task comment table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/GbCY8Dda)

[Task file table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/BgMfKk9N)

[Task step table and indexes](http://pastebin.com/mTJN379z)

[Invoice status table](http://pastebin.com/ZRZt7LcS)

[Opportunity table](http://pastebin.com/T8gYhP8e)

Is there something I can be doing better with the joins?  Make them subselects?

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Let me get them in there.

Comment: what are the relationships between the tables?

Comment: Added pastes of the table creates and index creates.

Comment: Uhh   the explain I linked should have those.

Comment: Sorry somehow overlooked that link

Comment: Are your statistics up to date? Line 10 and some above have a very big difference between the estimated row count and the actual row count.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do other than a vacuum analyze?  I did that not long before running the explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html).

```
CREATE INDEX idx_deleted_rows (some_id) ON some_table WHERE (deleted IS NULL);
```

Comment: What rows would you suggest this on?

Comment: If explain looks like this `Index Scan using idx_abc on some_table` followed by `Filter: (some_table.deleted IS NULL)`. In this example, you can add a partial index in addition to idx_abc.